# Shopify Polaris + React + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, shopify, polaris

I have struggled now for some days to get those 3 to work together for Shopify Embedded App: Polaris + React + Ruby on Rails 5.

Polaris is this: https://polaris.shopify.com

Is here somebody, who has got it all working together in Shopify Embedded App?

Maybe can share some empty "boilerplate" project where all those components are linked together, to see a working example?

My own version for public review is this, but I don't like it, so feel free to tell, how it's done better: https://github.com/marisveide/shopify-rails-react-polaris

Thanks!

Maris

Answer (score 1):

I am also about to embark on this journey. I found this [article](https://medium.com/@esimonian16/setting-up-a-shopify-app-with-rails-5-1-webpack-react-and-polaris-b8535d911275). It looks promising.
I might be pre-empting it as the boilerplate answer you asked for, but check it out, sounds like [Elizabeth Simonian](https://medium.com/@esimonian16) knows what she is talking about.